# нужна помощь в написании поискового метода в swift

Tags: ios, swift, поиск

У меня в приложении есть такая структура:

```
struct SubCategory {
    let code: String
    let description: String

    init (code: String, description: String) {
        self.code = code
        self.description = description
    }
}

struct Category {
    let code: String
    let description: String
    let subCategories: [SubCategory]
}

struct SubPosition {
    let code: String
    let description: String
    let categories: [Category]
}

struct Position {
    let code: String
    let description: String
    let subPositions: [SubPosition]
}

struct Group {
    let code: String
    let description: String
    let positions: [Position]
}

struct UKTZED {
    let groups: [Group] 
}
```

Эта структура презентована в приложении через динамический `UITableView`. В первом показаны строки с `groups`, при нажатии на которые презентуется новый `tableviewcontroller` с `position` и т.д.

Мне нужен поисковый метод, который бы осуществлял поиск одновременно по свойствам `code` и `description` на всех уровнях структуры (в `groups`, `positions`, `suppositions`, `categories` и `subcategories`), затемнял основной вид, показывал под поисковой ячейкой отфильтрованный список по результатам поиска и осуществлял `segue` при нажатии на строки в этом отфильтрованном списке. Реально ли совместить все эти "хотелки". Мне как новичку это кажется не по силам. Прошу помочь советом

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавьте в TableViewController UISearchController
2. Сделайте TableViewController делегатом UISearchResultsUpdating и UISearchControllerDelegate
3. Реализуйте их методы updateSearchResults и didDismissSearchController, в которых пропишите формирование условия для TableView, в виде измененного массива, например. И очистки условия при выходе из поиска.